# C++ retrieve a reference to an existing or new item in a list

Tags: c++, list, reference, iterator

I'm currently adding a function to my code that looks up an element in a list based on some key and then returns that element as a reference. If the key is not yet present in the list it should create a new element, add it to the end of the list and then return a reference to that element in the list such that when I edit it outside of the function it will be changed within the list. What would be the best way to do this?

Currently I have the following:

```
ElementType someElement;
getElementRefByKey (someList, someKey, someElement);
someElement.field = newField;

void getElementRefByKey (ListType &someList,
                         const int &someKey,
                         ElementType &someElement)
{
   for (ListType::iterator element_it = someList.begin();
        element_it != someList.end(); ++element_it)
   {
      if (element_it->key == someKey)
      {
         &someElement = &*element_it;
      }
   }

   ElementType newElement();
   newElement.key = someKey;
   someList.push_back(newElement);
   &someElement = &*someList.end()
}
```

I find the last part where I have to retrieve the last element again as a reference a bit ugly, is there a better way to do this or is this the correct way of doing what I described? Are there alternatives that are considered better practice in c++?

Many thanks in advance!

Regards,
Erik

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, my usage of pointers might still be incorrect in this example, this is a first draft, I'm trying to get it to work but I'm still quite new to c++ and am still struggling with pointer usage.

EDIT2: some people mentioned the use of a map. I understand that this would be better, but in this case I am given a list and a key and have to edit an element from that list based on that key. Also if the key is not present an element with that key should be generated. Someone suggested to me that I should use a function that would find or create the element and return a reference such that the code that needs to edit the element shouldn't worry about getting it from the list or creating it and putting it in the list.

Also, it's allowed to change the return type and parameter list of the function.

EDIT3:
Revised based on comments (this builds):

```
ElementType* someElement = getElementRefByKey (someList, someKey);
someElement->field = newField;

ListType::iterator getElementRefByKey (ListType &someList,
                                       const int &someKey)
{
   for (ListType::iterator element_it = someList.begin();
        element_it != someList.end(); ++element_it)
   {
      if (element_it->key == someKey)
      {
         return element_it;
      }
   }

   ElementType newElement;
   newElement.key = someKey;
   someList.push_back(newElement);
   return someList.end() - 1;
}
```

EDIT4:
A final question: is it bad practise to use `ElementType* someElement = func()` instead of `ListType::iterator someElement = func()` ?

Comment: If that's a `std::list`, that's more than just a bit ugly; its *undefined behavior*. You're dereferencing `end()`, which is *not* dereferencable. And this shouldn't even compile, `ElementType newElement();` declares a function, not a variable. Not even going to go into `&someElement` on the lhs of an assignment. To answer the actual question. Return an *iterator* to the element inserted or found.

Comment: It seems like you're reinventing `std::map` using a `list`. Is there a reason you need to use a linked list here?

Comment: I concur with @mattnewport completely. `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` would seem a significantly better approach to this.

Comment: I understand a map would be better, but all I get is the list, I cannot change it to a map as this is not part of my code.

Comment: Regarding the not dereferencable .end(): I'm not saying this code was already compiled, I'm still working on the actual design of this thing and as I'm quite new to c++ I'm struggling with how to use pointers correctly here.

Comment: Actually, ElementType newElement() works fine for me, in the code there is actually an initialization parameter within the brackets, but I thought for clarity it wouldn't matter if I included it here.

Comment: Perhaps update the question with what latitude you *do* have, because that information (can't use anything besides this list) should be there, not buried down here in comments. In particular, note whether or not the *parameter list* or the *return result* of this function can change (because it seriously needs to). Ideally the function returns an iterator to the location in the list, either the addition or the found-item. If you want to pass that iterator by reference, so be it, but the otherwise unused return result would likely be a better fit.

Comment: I added an update to the code based on your suggestions.

Comment: @WhozCraig You say I should return an iterator, do I define the return type of the function as ListType::iterator or can I use ElementType* as return type?

Comment: The former would likely do the job.

Comment: You mean get the pointer to it, not reference to it

Comment: Out of curiosity: in my example I use `ElementType element = *func()`, what would be the difference if I used `ElementType* element = func()` and then use `->` to access the fields, would that be the same memory usage wise?

Comment: @texasbruce Originally I thought I could retrieve the element by passing it by reference to the function, now after the comments I'm returning a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I was able to solve my problems and the piece of code below is the final function that does what I need it to do with the requirements that I got:

```
ElementType* someElement = getElementRefByKey (someList, someKey);
someElement->field = newField;

ListType::iterator getElementRefByKey (ListType &someList,
                                       const int &someKey)
{
   for (ListType::iterator element_it = someList.begin();
        element_it != someList.end(); ++element_it)
   {
      if (element_it->key == someKey)
      {
         return element_it;
      }
   }

   ElementType newElement;
   newElement.key = someKey;
   someList.push_back(newElement);
   return someList.end() - 1;
}
```

To recap my new insights that made it work:

- return the iterator itself when returning the last element that was
  added
- return the end() iterator minus 1 as end() is technically áfter the last
  element
- don't dereference the result, use the pointer directly